.Net 8 SDK update on Ubuntu 24.04
The current version of the.net 8 SDK on Ubuntu 24.04 is 8.0.105, but the latest is 8.0.302. Are there any plans to upgrade the package? When will it be available?
Tks


You can download the latest .NET 8 SDK 8.0.302 installer for Linux directly from Microsoft at https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0. This is a self-contained installer that won't interfere with system packages.
Overview of .NET on Ubuntu describes how to install .NET on Ubuntu.

However installing .NET 8 SDK using the built-in apt package tool with sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-8.0 offers some additional advantages over the first method.

No additional tools or configuration are needed.
Using the default Ubuntu repositories as a software source ensures the installed .NET 8 SDK works seamlessly with your Ubuntu OS.
You can use sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade for updating .NET 8 SDK and maybe eventually pick up an upgrade to version 8.0.302 or later that way.


The Ubuntu packages are indeed outdated.
The best alternative in such a case is to DNVM: https://dnvm.net
